# TypeError for a function with a string parameter

Tags: python, function, methods

I am trying to create a simple function that allows me to return a string reversed. However, when I call the function, the error

```
TypeError: reverseString() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

comes up. I'm more familiar with Java, and was wondering what the problem is and if passing a string parameter is the same in Python.

```
  Class myString()

        def reverseString(string):
              return string[:,:,-1]

  p = myString()
  p.reversedString('Eric')
```

Comment: Is this function *actually a method* in a class definition? Are you calling this method on an instance of some class? You need to provide the calling code, at the *very least*.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: [Python isn't Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html), you don't need to wrap everything in classes. Also it's case sensitive, so what you've posted doesn't actually work at all. But if you do want to have that as a method in a class (rather than a function, which would be simpler), it needs the `self` argument. I'd recommend running through a tutorial: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 4):

Python requires a special first parameter for methods to which it passes the instance that the method is being called on. You *can* use pretty much any valid variable name, but it's a Python convention to use `self` and it will make your code easier for other people to read.

```
class myString:    
     def reverseString(self, string):
         return string[::-1]

p = myString()
print(p.reverseString('Eric'))
```

To access instance variables, you would use `self.var` - you can't just do `var` like in Java.

Also, as @jonrshape pointed out in the comments, you don't need to wrap functions in a class:

```
def reverseString(string):
    return string[::-1]

print(reverseString('Eric'))
```

Comment: No, this is definitely not what `@classmethod` is for. That's bad bad bad advice. Especially for someone coming to Python from Java.

Comment: One more thing, `this` and `self` work quite differently. `self` isn't a keyword in Python, indeed, you can use *any name you want* as long as it is the first parameter to the function definition. Also, most of the time you can leave out the `this` in Java, because instance variables are declared in the class definition. Python doesn't have variable declarations. You need to explicitly use `self.whatever` for instance attributes. Instance attributes in Python can be created in any method.

Comment: Great, thank you and everyone else for their feedback. I probably should look more into some tutorials/documentations before I continue on!

Comment: @Eric101 yes, it's sort of a mantra you can repeat: "Python is not Java (thank Guido)...Python is not Java (thank Guido)..."